# Are GKE internal load balancers accessible from the cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I deployed an API that was exposed by an internal load balancer. I tried to make a get request to the API from cloud shell and the request would hang and timeout. I then switched the load balancer from an internal to an external load balancer and was able to make the request. Are internal load balancers on GCP inaccessible from the cloud shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Internal Load Balancers` are not global by default and can only be accessed from the same network or same region as the cluster unless [global access](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#global_access) is enabled.

[Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#zone_selection) is globally distributed across multiple GCP regions. When a user connects for the first time, the system assigns them to the geographically closest region that can accommodate new users. While the users cannot manually chose their region, the system does its best to pick the closest region Cloud Shell operates in. If Cloud Shell does not initially pick the closest region or if the user later connects from a location that's geographically closer to a different region, Cloud Shell will migrate the user to a closer region on session end.